# Package Customize Routing in Laravel without editing routes

Tags: laravel-4, package, laravel-routing

I am developing an application with Laravel 4, I need to develop an admin package for my application I have seen many packages that automatically edited routes.php file of the application,

The Question:
How to develop such package that automatically creates its own routes without editing the routes.php file manually? for example after adding the package to application an URL like myapplication/admin added to the application

Comment: When including the packages service provider, the boot method you have within your service provider should include the routes.php found within the packages source files, allowing you to access the routes within the package. [Source found here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#package-routing)

Comment: That should be everything, make sure you run the command composer dump-autoload to make sure your autoload files are up to date.

Comment: Thanks very much I removed my comment because I solved it just few seconds you left comment anyway your comments were very helpful

Comment: Ill add as answer and you can add what you needed to do so other people know what to do :) and yw. @Siavosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When including the packages service provider, the boot method you have within your service provider should include the routes.php found within the packages source files, allowing you to access the routes within the package. Like the following;

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->package('vendor/package');

    include __DIR__.'/../../routes.php';
}
```

[Source found here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#package-routing)